# How to Make a "relative path" alias or symbolic link in osx?

Tags: macos, installation, alias, relative-path, symlink

I need a link. It´s for a software delivery DMG file. It is rather simple. But I do not know programming very well.

My need is to get an **alias** or a **symbolic link** that links to a relative path, like this:

/users/USERFOLDER-name/Library/Application Support/Some Folder/some other folder/ etc...

How is this done? Through some form of apple script? Is there a way to do it with a script or a program??

Hope someone can help, I do not know programming very well though...

Comment: Can you clarify the ".../USERFOLDER-name/..." part -- is it supposed to figure out the current user? If so, that's beyond what either an alias or a symlink can do.

Answer (score 1):

An alias can be created in Finder's context menu.

(Symbolic) links can be generated (as in any unix) by `ln -s <original_path> <alias_path>`.

**EDIT**

You must input the code in a shell. The standard shell for OSX is `bash`. You can open a shell (start) a shell by some terminal program, typically `Terminal.app`. 
You will get more information on `ln` there, if you type `man ln`.

Comment: How nice. Thanks for the info. However, I do not know what that code is supposed to be handled. Where do I put that code? In terminal? In apple script editor?